# Facing issues merging develop to release branch after feature branch got merged to release directly

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging, merge-conflict-resolution

The way our repo is set up is `feature` branch to `develop` to `release` branch to generate production build. i.e

`feature` -> `develop` -> `release`

But over the weekend, team merged some hot fixes directly to release. Now release is ahead of develop. On trying to bring `develop` in sync with `release` facing lots of issues.

I tried to cherry-pick the hot fixes from `release` into `develop` - skipped the merge commits though. But even after merging my cherry-picked PR - I see conflicts when trying to raise PR from `develop` to `release`

What am I missing here?
Is there a way to fix this? Or should we create a new develop branch instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have an `hot-fix` *branch* that you:

- merge to `release`
- *and* you merge to `develop`

that way, Git has recorded *merge commits* (instead of regular commits through cherry-pick), and that should avoid conflicts, when you PR from `develop` to `release` later on.